# What does "roughly equal sample sizes" mean?

Tags: sample-size

"Roughly equal" is ambiguous. My professor told me to use the cut off ratio of 1.5 to determine if my two sample sizes are roughly equal (i.e., n1 divided by n2) but I cannot find the citation. Can someone please tell who stated this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It’s just a colloquial expression. There’s no mathematical rigor to be found here.